# Joining laboratory values in SQL with time conditions

Tags: sql, join

I have a data set of laboratory measurements. First, I'm fetching all the values of measurement A with patient IDs included. Then, I'm trying to join earliest and latest dates of measurement B and their respective values within a specific time frame:

```
SELECT  
    A.patient_id,   
    A.time AS A_time,  
    A.value AS A_value,
    MIN(B.time) AS earliest_B_time,
    MAX(B.time) AS latest_B_time,
FROM  
    schema.measurements A 
LEFT JOIN
    schema.measurements B
    ON A.pat_id = B.pat_id
WHERE
    B.name= 'B'
    AND A.name = 'A'
    AND B.time <= A.time
    AND B.time >= (A.time - 90)
GROUP BY
    A.pat_id,   
    A.time,  
    A.value
```

With this, I'm getting the earliest and latest B times but not their respective measurement values. Is there a nice way to have them included without doing another join with the same measurements table?

Comment: Start with moving all table B conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. (Or switch to INNER JOIN, if that's what you want.)

Comment: A [mcve] would make this clearer.

Comment: Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It would really help to see the schema of the table and some representative example data. You're returning A.patient_id in the SELECT clause, but self-joining the table on pat_id - do both of these fields really exist and if so, what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use window functions to achieve this:

```
select distinct
    A.patient_id,
    A.[time] as A_time,
    A.[value] as A_value,
    first_value(B.[time]) over (partition by B.patient_id order by B.[time] rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as earliest_B_time,
    last_value(B.[time]) over (partition by B.patient_id order by B.[time] rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as latest_B_time,
    first_value(B.[value]) over (partition by B.patient_id order by B.[time] rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as earliest_B_value,
    last_value(B.[value]) over (partition by B.patient_id order by B.[time] rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as latest_B_value
from [schema].measurements A
left join [schema].measurements B
    on A.patient_id = B.patient_id
    and B.[name] = 'B'
    and B.[time] <= A.[time]
    and B.[time] >= (A.[time] - 90)
where A.[name] = 'A'
```

Comment: Note that OP hasn't specified dbms, so SQL Server square brackets as delimiters is perhaps not accurate.

Comment: Yes, fair point, just force of habit for me when writing up the query to avoid reserved keywords being highlighted, but you're right, this syntax might not be valid depending on DBMS.